# Error al ejecutar proyecto laravel clonado de git

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, git

Cloné un proyecto de un repo git. Cuando lo trato de abrir (http://localhost/proyecto/public/) me dice lo siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pikum.mapu\bootstrap\app.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pikum.mapu\public\index.php(38): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pikum.mapu\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Y ese proyecto lo habia hecho yo y estaba bien, me sale el mismo error al ejecutar php artisan serve. ¿Qué podria ser? No sé si se debe hacer algo antes de ejecutar un proyecto laravel

Comment: ya realizaste el `composer install` luego de clonar el proyecto?

Comment: gracias por responder, esto lo hago en la carpeta del proyecto? ya lo intento ... si , era eso pero ahora me dice cuando corro el proyecto "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: Puedes poner mas información sobre el nuevo error?

Comment: bueno mejor reviso porque creo que unos amigos le cambiaron varias cosas entonces quizas este buscando cosas que ya no estan pero muchas gracias amigo ! ! ! y bueno solo me dice eso jaja

Comment: Es que si solo te dice eso, quizá este con `APP_DEBUG=false`, asegúrate de tener el fichero .env en la carpeta de tu proyecto y configuralo con tus variables de entorno (base de datos, entre otros) y recuerda dejar el `APP_DEBUG= true` mientras estés desarrollando. Suerte

Comment: acabo de revisar y si tiene eso en true, en la base de datos tiene homestead al igual que usuario y de pass tiene secret, lo cambie a mi db y sigue diciendo lo mismo y en el inspector no veo ningun error, no me deberia aparecer al menos una pantalla , que raro :/

Comment: intenta correrlo el proyecto con un `php artisan serve`, si estas en windows debes agregar php a tus variables de entorno o ejecutar php directamente desde el directorio donde esta instalado probablemente es `c:\xampp\php\php.exe artisan serve`.

Comment: ya vi el .env estaba asi .env.example asi que le quite el .example , luego me decia : "No application encryption key has been specified." pero lo resolvi con esto php artisan key:generate. Muchas gracias espero que esta pregunta le sirva a alguien mas :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

es por que cuando lo clonas del **repositorio oficial**, las dependencias no están listas; es decir no existen dentro del proyecto pero finalmente se soluciona haciendo

`composer install`

¿De donde sabe que paquetes o dependencias instalar?

Bueno en la raíz de tu proyecto existe un archivo llamado *composer.json* dentro del cual existe una sección que dice por ejemplo `require-dev` que son las dependencias requeridas para development y las comenzará a bajar

dentro de la carpeta raíz; te pongo como ejemplo que esta es la misma situación que se presenta cuando estas trabajando un proyecto construido sobre NodeJS si no haces

`npm install`

igual marca errores.

Saludos

Comment: excelente, gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas recomendable en estos casos es que después de clonar el proyecto desde [GitHub](https://github.com), es instalar las dependencias del proyecto nuevamente por lo que desde la terminal y dentro de la carpeta del proyecto que clonaste escribe:

```
composer install
```

cuando clonas un repositorio con un proyecto de Laravel, no se guarda el archivo .env en dicho repositorio por cuestiones de seguridad y Configuración de Laravel ([Revisa la Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration)), pero si se guarda el archivo .env.example que prácticamente es el mismo; y pues lo único que tienes que hacer es hacer un Guardar Como (Save As...) con el nombre .env ; Y eso es todo... espero te sirva.

Recuerda que si estas utilizando Valet debes reiniciar dichos servicios:

```
valet restart
```